# Is there a way to use a wildcard to get ZSet members in Redis?

Tags: redis

Something to ZSet members just as `KEYS` command to common keys.

Comment: No. But you can probably write one in server-side Lua if you like to implement horrible O(n) algorithms.

Comment: It should also be noted that you should *not* use `KEYS` in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible with base commands, maybe you can work something out with lua script.
personally I prefer to solve this kind of problems at app level by adding indexes (store keys/members in separate keys).

Btw, you should not use the KEYS command for non development environments (or unless you have a very limited amount of keys)